# get the last modified file in ftp with bash script

Tags: ftp

With bash Script, I would like to get the last modified file in ftp remote.
On remote ftp dir, I have files like this :

test-01.zip 
test-02.zip 
test-03.zip  
test-04.zip

My aim is to get the last modified file with bash script.

Can help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can get last modified date by

```
ls -lt
```

then get it

Comment: Just for clarity, it would be good if you could include an example.